# How to make automation apps for android

Tags: android, selenium, automation, appium, ui-automation

How to make an app which can automate tasks like liking every post in my feed on Instagram.
To make such apps what i'll have to learn other than android studio?

Comment: You means to write an automation script to like every post in feed on instagram ?

Comment: @AmitJain i want my app to do so

Comment: then you should remove automation related tags and add Android tags to get help.

Comment: @AmitJain I thought this might come under automation because app will run web-view heedlessly and open Instagram and click on the like buttons.

Answer (score 0):

You need to learn appium to automate android apps. But ideally you can automate development builds not the builds which are released.